# Wordpress http post 404

Tags: wordpress, http, post, http-status-code-404

I have an error in WP that every time I http post I get a 404

I have ready about the error with field names and it is not that, if the fields are named random names, or their are no fields, I still get the 404 error.

It happens with any http post I get a 404, if it is on the same server or not.

This only happens when permalink is set to "Post name"

Any help fixing this error would be gratefully appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Cleared the cache and restarted the router (dynamic IP) and it worked, host must have confused me with a hacker